# Should I use Pre Get Posts or WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts

I have the following query which I call in my taxonomy.php template via `query_brands_geo('dealers', 'publish', '1', $taxtype, $geo, $brands);`

This function works perfectly. However after reading codex for query posts it mentioned pre_get_posts as a preferred way to alter the default query.  Would the pre_get_posts be more efficient then my wp_query function below?

If so how would I construct the pre_get_posts and pass my variable and query below?

```
function my_custom_query($posttype, $poststatus, $paidvalue, $taxtype, $geo, $brands) {
   global $wp_query; 
   $wp_query = new WP_Query();
   $args = array( 
      'post_type' => $posttype, 
      'post_status' => array($poststatus), 
      'orderby' => 'rand', 
      'posts_per_page' => 30, 
      'meta_query' => array( 
         array( 
            'key' => 'wpcf-paid', 
            'value' => array($paidvalue), 
            'compare' => 'IN', 
            ) 
      ), 
      'tax_query' => array( 
         'relation' => 'AND', 
         array( 
            'taxonomy' => $taxtype, 
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => $geo 
         ), 
         array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'brands', 
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => $brands 
         ) 
      ) 
   ); 

   return $wp_query->query($args); 
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pre_get_posts` will run the same query, so both will take same time. But, If you utilize `pre_get_posts` action you will save one or more SQL queries. Right now, WordPress is running default query and then you run your query with this function which replace the results of the default query (resulting, default query is of no use). Below is how you can move your `$args` to

```
function custom_pre_get_posts($query, $posttype='dealers', $poststatus='publish', $paidvalue='1', $taxtype='any_default_value', $geo='any_default_value', $brands='any_default_value') {

    // filter your request here.
    if($query->is_category) {

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $posttype,
            'post_status' => array($poststatus),
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => 30,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-paid',
                    'value' => array($paidvalue),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                )
            ),
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxtype,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $geo
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'brands',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $brands
                )
            )
        );
        $query->query_vars = $args;
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.  It is very helpful.  One quick question. I placed the function in my theme function.php file. I run this function custom_pre_get_posts($query) from my taxonomy.php.  In the taxonomy.php I set up the variables, $posttype, $post_status, $geo, $brands, $taxtype and run two loops changing these variable.  Is there a way to pass variable into the above function from taxonomy.php?  When I try custom_pre_get_posts($query,'dealers', 'publish', '1', $taxtype, $geo, $brands); I get Missing argument 2 thru 7 for custom_pre_get_posts(). I assume due to add_action???

Comment: I am assuming you changed the  custom_pre_get_posts to accept the remaining arguments. Yes, you are getting error because of add_action. add_action calls this function with single argument (i.e. $query), you should give default values to other arguments to avoid missing argument errors. like ($posttype=null, $poststatus=null...) so it can properly called by add_action.

Comment: M-R Thank you for the reply.  I read up on add action and I see I should be assigning a priority and arguments number.  So I changed my add action to <code>add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts', 10,7);</code>  Then in my taxonomy.php page I <code> do_action('pre_get_post', $query, 'dealers', 'publish', '1', $taxtype, $geo, $brands);</code>.  But I am still getting the same error.  I was not sure where to put default values.  I tried google but could not find a reference. Can you give me a little more information on where how to handle this?

Comment: Thank you for the reply and example.  But I think I might be trying to use pre_get_posts when I should just be doing a new wordpress query.  I was trying to save a query, but in my case it might not be possible.  The reason being is all the arguments you set in the parameter, I wanted to pass to the function from my taxonomy.php file.  So  $paidvalue=”1” might be 1 or 0 depending on which condition I am executing in taxonomy.php.  It seems pre_get_posts above fires right when the page loads even if I don't call the function in my taxonomy.php file.  Am I seeing this correct?

Comment: I get the same feeling earlier when you explained that you want to call it multiple times. Instead of saving a query, stay with organised and structured approach.

Comment: This answer is **non sense** as it's currently written. You will effectivly **overwrite** any value inside the `$wp_query` object and things will completely fail. Aside from that it's simply **not true** that `pre_get_posts` will run an additional query...

Answer (score 10):

*Late answer as the most upvoted answer will break your query and simply isn't true in some major points.*

### The *main* WP_Query and it's filters

First, WordPress internally uses `query_posts()` (a thin wrapper around `WP_Query` that **shouldn't** be used in themes or plugins) to do a `WP_Query`. This `WP_Query` is acting as the main loop/query. This query will run through a lot of filters and actions until the actual SQL query string is built. One of those is `pre_get_posts`. Others are `posts_clauses`, `posts_where`, etc. that **also** allow you to intercept the query string building process.

An in depth look at what happens inside core

> WordPress runs the `wp()` function (in `wp-includes/functions.php`), which calls `$wp->main()` (`$wp` is an object of class WP, which is defined in `wp-includes/class-wp.php`). This tells WordPress to:
>
> 1. Parse the URL into a query specification using `WP->parse_request()` -- more on that below.
> 2. Set all the is_ variables that are used by Conditional Tags using `$wp_query->parse_query()` (`$wp_query` is an object of `class WP_Query`, which is defined in `wp-includes/query.php`). Note that in spite of this function's name, in this case `WP_Query->parse_query` doesn't actually do any parsing for us, since that is done before-hand by `WP->parse_request()`.
> 3. Convert the query specification into a MySQL database query, and run the database query to get the list of posts, in function WP_Query->get_posts(). Save the posts in the $wp_query object to be used in the WordPress Loop.
>
> <sup>Source [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview)</sup>

## Conclusion

If you really want to modify the main query, then you can use a wide variety of filters. Simply use `$query->set( 'some_key', 'some_value' );` to **change** data there or use `$query->get( 'some_key' );` to **retrieve** data to do conditional checks. This will save you from doing a second query, as you're **altering** the SQL query only.

If you have to do an **additional** query, then go with a `WP_Query` object. This will add another query to the DB.

### Example

As answers always work better with an example, you here got one really nice one (props to Brad Touesnard), that simply extends the core object and therefore is pretty reusable (make a plugin out of it):

```
class My_Book_Query extends WP_Query
{
    function __construct( $args = array() )
    {
        // Forced/default args
        $args = array_merge( $args, array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        ) );

        add_filter( 'posts_fields', array( $this, 'posts_fields' ) );

        parent::__construct( $args );
    }

    public function posts_fields( $sql )
    {
        return "{$sql}, {$GLOBALS['wpdb']->terms}.name AS 'book_category'";
    }
}
```

You can then run your *second*/additional query like you can see in the following example. Don't forget to reset your query afterwards.

```
$book_query = new My_Book_Query();
if ( $book_query->have_posts() )
{
    while ( $book_query->have_posts() )
    {
        $book_query->the_post();
        # ...do stuff...
    } // endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
} // endif;
```

Answer (score 6):

Please check out the answers at [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts).

It is a great ressource if you have any doubts in mind.